Bond film where Bond and the Bond girl cuddle up seen in infra red
Title says it all really, I'm trying to find the scene where bond and the bond girl are cuddling up seen in infra-red. I believe they're in a boat and I think it's an end scene, but I've tried to watch the end scene of each film and I can't find it!

Random downvote without a reason.

The movie you're looking for is The World is not enough. More specifically the gadget you're looking for is Thermo Satellite Locator 
